# Не работает SeekBar в mediplayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Пытаюсь обновлять seekBar при проигрывание , мелодии беру из массива, все воспроизводиться и работает корректно, не могу обновлять seekBar,т.е при перемещении бара мелодия повторяется заново и секкбар не перемещается.
Вызываю в:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootViewB = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        seekBar = (SeekBar)rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.sbar);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        startMediaPlayer();
        setSeekBar();



  public void startMediaPlayer(){
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });
        /////////////
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent)
            {

                seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                 seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(mp.getDuration() / 100*percent);

                seekBar.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition());
      *      }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем, не знаю насколько это правильно с точки зрения программирования,все работает:

```
 private Runnable onEverySecond=new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if(seekBar != null) {
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            }

            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                seekBar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
            }

        }
    };
    public void startMediaPlayer(){
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                seekBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                seekBar.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
               }
public void setSeekBar(){
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBars, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            if(mediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`startPlayProgressUpdater()` В теле onCreateView вы вызываете до инициализации `seekBar`, то есть до  `seekBar = (SeekBar)rootViewB.findViewById(R.id.sbar);`

Повесьте на ваш сикбар слушатель для его обновления

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {                
                if(mMediaPlayer != null){
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
                }
            }
    });
```

В `initView()` `setOnTouchListener` можете удалить полностью. А в `startPlayProgressUpdater()` исправьте  `seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000);`

Comment: исправил в шапке,однако не обновляется сеекбар..хотя должен

Answer (score 0):

Общий алгоритм таков:
При старте воспроизведения получаем и устанавливаем в SeekBar длину трека

```
mSeekBar.setMax(mMediaPlayer.getDuration())
```

затем стартуем обновление SeekBar каждую секунду

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(mMediaPlayer != null){
            int mCurrentPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            mSeekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
});
```

*Не забывайте очищать handler при остановке и запускать заново при старте воспроизведения файла.*
После этого устанавливаем слушатель на SeekBar, что бы перематывать MediaPlayer

```
mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {                
                if(mMediaPlayer != null && fromUser){
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }
    });
```

Comment: исправил код в шапке,но сеекбар не обновляется.
а можно подробнее про это:
Не забывайте очищать handler при остановке и запускать заново при старте воспроизведения файла.